# Normalization of input in NN for numeric values

Tags: tensorflow, neural-network, deep-learning, keras

I read a lot of papers concerning the normalization of image in CNN.
But I didn't find answers for this case.
Let's says, the input of my first layer is :
[1, 4234, 90420394.43, 0]
Do I have to normalize it ?
Because, the gradient descent should be able to recognize itself what are the important parameters and how to handle it with the W's matrix no ?

And last question, if I really have to normalize this, will I have a vector of value between 0 and 1 ?
Isn't the information lost ?
(And because it just seems to be a rescale, the relative difference stays the same, so, what is the matter in this case ?)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer is not specific to images in CNNs, but rather to neural networks in general. Your intuition that gradient descent should just work it out is correct, the system should learn to scale naturally, but **having inputs on the same** scale helps keep gradient steps on the same scale, which will help your network converge faster (without this, it is possible a network may not converge).

Additionally, techniques like regularization work with the weight values directly, so may be affected by unbalanced scales.

There is also [batch normalization](https://gab41.lab41.org/batch-normalization-what-the-hey-d480039a9e3b), which is often used in image CNNs, and does not relate to normalizing input values.